# li in htmlagilitypack c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to get label and strong values from the following li

```
<div class="property-summary">
    <h3>Listing summary</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Reference</label>
            <strong>BR-S-4301</strong>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>Type</label>
            <strong>Apartment</strong>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>City</label>
            <strong>Dubai</strong>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>Community</label>
            <strong>Palm Jumeirah</strong>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>Subcommunity</label>
            <strong>Tiara Residences</strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my c# code

```
 var dataNode = rootNode.SelectNodes("//div[normalize-space(@class)='property-summary']");
```

Now how to get it? below is not working for me

```
 var Node = dataNode .SelectSingleNode(".//li/strong");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do it.

## 1

```
var labelNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[normalize-space(@class)='property-summary']/ul/li/label");
var strongNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[normalize-space(@class)='property-summary']/ul/li/strong");

foreach (var node in labelNodes)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
}
foreach (var node in strongNodes)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
}
```

## 2

```
var liNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[normalize-space(@class)='property-summary']/ul/li");

foreach (var node in liNodes)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("label").InnerText.Trim());
    Debug.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("strong").InnerText.Trim());
}
```

check for existence of nodes before writing any real code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the `label` tags, you can use

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> labels = dataNode.Descendants("label");
```

And same for `strong` tags

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> strongs = dataNode.Descendants("strong");
```

You can also use:

```
var dataNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[normalize-space(@class)='property-summary']")[0];
HtmlNodeCollection strongs = dataNode.SelectNodes(".//li/strong");
HtmlNodeCollection labels = dataNode.SelectNodes(".//li/label");
```

To get text from strongs or labels use:

```
foreach (var strong in strongs)
{
    string strongText = strong.InnerText.Trim();
}
```

Comment: it will give me li values? or just one..we should not have loop?

Comment: It will return all the labels/strongs which are in 'property-summary' div

Comment: I want to get values..like Reference or type or city etc etc...how i can get those?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider switching to these HTML parsing libraries which provide excellent jQuery selectors like features.

http://nsoup.codeplex.com/

http://github.com/jamietre/csquery